# Can I shorten these str.replace calls?

Tags: python

As part of a script, I have:

```
text = text.replace('?',' ')
text = text.replace(',',' ')
text = text.replace('.',' ')
text = text.replace(' ','- ')
```

Is there a way to do all this with one line?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions to the rescue!

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'[?,. ]', '- ', text)
```

Comment: Is it works correctly? ,Because ` ` only should be repalce by `- ` not all of symbols

Comment: @tjohnson: The code in the question replaces `?,.` with spaces, and then replaces the spaces (both those originally in `text` and those substituted in) with `- `, which is what my code does.

Comment: @tjohnson: And then after that, `text = text.replace(' ', '- ')` replaces all of those single spaces with `- `.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a more Pythonic way, but:

```
text = text.replace('?',' ').replace(',',' ').replace('.',' ').replace(' ','- ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't very Pythonic either, but it works without needing to import the `re` module:

```
text = "".join((i if i not in '?,.' else '- ' for i in text))
```